# List comprehension on two lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say I have two equal-length lists, `list1` and `list2`, both consisting of a bunch of numbers.  I want to remove all the elements of `list1` that don't meet a certain criterion.  Simple enough.  How would I also remove the corresponding elements from `list2` though?  If I remove, say, the 5th element of `list1`, I would also like to remove the 5th element of `list2`.  Example of what I'm trying to do below:

```
list1 = [i for i in list1 if i >= 1]
list2 = list2 #but with the corresponding values of list1 removed from list2 as well
```

I could come up with, say,

```
list2_temp = []
for j in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[j] >= 1:
        list2_temp.extend(list2[j])

list1 = [i for i in list1 if i >= 1]
```

but I am looking for a more "Pythonic" way to do it, specifically if there is any way I can use list comprehensions on `list2` as well as `list1`.  Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine, filter, split:

```
list1[:], list2[:] = zip(*((x, y) for (x, y) in zip(list1, list2) if predicate(x)))
```

Comment: if for each `x`s in predicate are `False` ..... `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack` ...... how can i fix this ?

Comment: Defer the assignment until you can check if there's any results, and then use `del list1[:], list2[:]` if there aren't any.

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe the problem is that you have 2 parallel lists rather than a single list that holds items which have the all the data for each element.

Think of the data as a spreadsheet -- Currently you have 2 columns and you want to filter the rows by the values in one column.  Rather than modeling the data as a bunch of columns, it's better to model it as a list of rows.

To fix the problem *now* you can zip the lists together, filter them and then unzip at the end:

```
items = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(list1, list2) if i >= 1]
tuple1, tuple2 = zip(*items)
```

but I still recommend *considering* storing the data in a different way...